# How can I method in the other method?

Tags: java, methods, parameters

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyCoffeeOutlet {


    //Hold the value of original price
    public static double originalPrice(int bag) {

        final double COFFE_PRICE = 5.50; // The price of coffe per bag

        double originalPrice = 0;
        originalPrice = bag * COFFE_PRICE; // before discounted price

        return originalPrice;
    }

    //Hold the value of discounted price
    public static double discountPrice(double discount) {

        double discountPrice = 0;
        discountPrice = originalPrice(bagsAmount) * discount; // to find discount price

        return discountPrice;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // To hold the Total bag amount
        int bagsAmount = 0;


        // to hold the value of total price 
        double totalPrice, discount = 0;

        // To show how much discounted.
        int percent1 = 5,
            percent2 = 10,
            percent3 = 15,
            percent4 = 20,
            percent5 = 25,
            percent6 = 30;


        // to put suitable percent in to this variable
        int percent = 0;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Get the bag amount from the Customer
        System.out.println("How many bags do you want to buy? : ");

        bagsAmount = scanner.nextInt();

        // If it under 0, it will not count.
        while (bagsAmount < 0) {

            System.out.println("Input positive number or zero");
            System.out.println("How many bags do you want to buy? : ");

            bagsAmount = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        scanner.close();

        // How much the customer get the discount?
        if( bagsAmount >= 25 && bagsAmount < 50) {
            discount = 0.05;

            originalPrice(bagsAmount);

            discountPrice(discount);

            totalPrice = originalPrice(bagsAmount) - discountPrice(discount);

            percent = percent1;
        } else if (bagsAmount >= 50 && bagsAmount < 100 ) {
            discount = 0.1;

            originalPrice(bagsAmount);

            discountPrice(discount);

            totalPrice = originalPrice(bagsAmount) - discountPrice(discount);

            percent = percent2;
        } else if (bagsAmount >= 100 && bagsAmount < 150) {
            discount = 0.15;

            originalPrice(bagsAmount);

            discountPrice(discount);

            totalPrice = originalPrice(bagsAmount) - discountPrice(discount);

            percent = percent3;
        } else if (bagsAmount >= 150 && bagsAmount < 200) {
            discount = 0.2;

            originalPrice(bagsAmount);

            discountPrice(discount);

            totalPrice = originalPrice(bagsAmount) - discountPrice(discount);

            percent = percent4;
        } else if (bagsAmount >= 200 && bagsAmount < 300) {
            discount = 0.25;

            originalPrice(bagsAmount);

            discountPrice(discount);

            totalPrice = originalPrice(bagsAmount) - discountPrice(discount);

            percent = percent5;
        } else if (bagsAmount >= 300) {
            discount = 0.3;

            originalPrice(bagsAmount);

            discountPrice(discount);

            totalPrice = originalPrice(bagsAmount) - discountPrice(discount);

            percent = percent6;
        } else {
            totalPrice = originalPrice(bagsAmount);
        }

        System.out.println("Number of Bags Ordered : " + bagsAmount + " - " + " $ " 
                                                                    + originalPrice(bagsAmount));

        System.out.println("\t" + "      Discount :" + "\n\t\t\t " 
                                    + percent + "%" + " - $  " + discountPrice(discount));

        System.out.println("Your total charge is : " + " $ " + totalPrice);
    }

}
```

This is my code. I want to use originalPrice method into the discountPrice method. but I don't have any idea how to get the parameter into the originalPrice for using in the discountPrice method. I want to make an output to the console using if statment. How can I use originalPrice method directly? **

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Since originalPrice is a public static method you can use it like this: MyCoffeeOutlet.originalPrice(paramHere)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly. From what I understand, you want to be able to use your method `originalPrice()` inside your method `discountPrice()`. The problem you are having is that `orignalPrice()` accepts a number of bags, but you don't have that information in `discountPrice()`.

If that is your question, the easiest way to fix that, is to have `discountPrice()` accept the discount amount *and* the number of bags. As in:

`public static double discountPrice(double discount, int bagsAmount){ }`

Then, when you call the `discountPrice()` method, make sure to send both pieces of information.